# How to get current User in base class of service layer in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

There are answers how to get User principal in service layer using `IHttpContextAccessor` but they are always related to getting the user in service itself, not in its base (abstract class).

I have following situation:

There is an `UserService` which is injected in controller which needs it like this:

```
private IUserService UserService;
public UserController(IUserService userService)
{
    UserService = userService;
}
```

Pretty standard, this is service layer for getting/posting/patching... user. Problem is, this `UserService` inherits something called `ServiceBase`:

```
public class UserService : ServiceBase, IUserService
{
    private IDatabaseService DatabaseService;
    public UserService(IDatabaseService databaseService, ServiceManager serviceManager) : base(serviceManager)
    {
        DatabaseService = databaseService;
    }
.. rest of code omitted ...
```

and `ServiceBase` looks like this:

```
public abstract class ServiceBase
{
    internal static readonly NLog.Logger log = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private ServiceManager ServiceManager;

    public ServiceBase(ServiceManager serviceManager)
    {
        ServiceManager = serviceManager;
    }
 ... rest of code omitted...
```

Now, if I wanted to use `IHttpContextAccessor` I would have to inject it in each of services so it can be passed to `ServiceBase`, much like `ServiceManager` (another singleton service, not related to this question) is passed to it. Reason why `ServiceBase` is needed is for logging and more importantly, providing a way for each of services to post changes made by them (post, patch, delete) to rest of microservices.

Startup looks like this:

```
 services.AddSingleton<ServiceManager>();
 services.AddHostedService(provider => provider.GetService<ServiceManager>());

 services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
 services.AddScoped<IDatabaseService, DatabaseService>();
 services.AddScoped<ILoginService, LoginService>();
 services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
```

Is there a way to get `IHttpContextAccessor` in this `ServiceBase` without passing it around? Same question could be asked for `ServiceManager` since that dependancy also has to be passed from implementation to base class? What I want is to know which user did call the controller action (and consequently the service layer) without writing bunch of boilerplate code in each of controllers and/or services.

Another way of asking would be is it possible to resolve singleton services like `IHttpContextAccessor` and `ServiceManager` inside service layer without injecting them in each service?

Comment: There are some methods to pass the objects: via constructor (injected or not), via property (injected or set), cross-cutting via method interception. I do prefer injecting everything via constructor. Even to the base class. Several dependencies is completely fine but when it goes to many (e.g: more than 6), you should consider refactoring it to follow the Single Responsibility principle. When deriving the base class, you don't need to type everything, Visual Studio supports auto-gen the constructor conveniently. That's why I can feel happy with constructor injection in such scenario.

Comment: ```HttpContext.User``` should be available without any need for passing through constructors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

Bad answer: You shouldn't. [But you can with a ServiceLocator](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/05/06/servicelocator-shim-for-net-core/).

Alternate answer: we can make the paramter transfer less pain.

Instead of passing `ServiceManager` to the base class, pass a `ServiceBaseServiceContext` to it:

```
public class ServiceBaseServiceContext
{
    public ServiceManager ServiceManager {get;}
    public IUserService UserService {get;}

    public ServiceBaseServiceContext(ServiceManager serviceManager, IUserService userService)
    {
        ServiceManager = serviceManager;
        UserService = userService;
    }
}
```

This way, you have only one Parameter, regardless how many services you need.

```
public abstract class ServiceBase
{
    private ServiceManager _serviceManager;
    private IUserService_userService;

    public ServiceBase(ServiceBaseServiceContext serviceContext)
    {
        _serviceManager = serviceContext.ServiceManager;
        _userService = serviceContext.UserService;
    }
}
```

`ServiceBaseServiceContext` needs also to be registered in your ServiceCollection to make it work:

```
// depending on the services maybe Scoped
services.AddTransient<ServiceBaseServiceContext>();
```

Instead of making a `ServiceBaseServiceContext` you could also pass a `IServiceProvider` to `ServiceBase`, but this would be the same as a ServiceLocator, which is bad, because it hides the dependencies.

Comment: I've ran into similar concept but you explained it much more clearly. I'll try this approach if more services or dependencies are added, simple passing through base constructor will do for now. Thank you!